# External thread exception doesn't catched in the DispatcherUnhandledException event

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, exception, dispatcher

I'm trying to handle any background thread exception using the [App.DispatcherUnhandledException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception) event because I'm comprehensively catch them and writing them to the log there.
I have tried to do it that way below but the event doesn't got raised and my app got crashed.

```
public class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        client = new Client();
        client.OnSocketError += (s, e) => Dispatcher.Invoke(() => throw e.Exception); // re-throwing
        client.Connect("192.168.1.5", "1234");
    }
}
```

It is possible to re-throw the exception to the main thread?

Note that event got raised when the exception thrown from the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced this line:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => throw e.Exception);
```

With this one:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => throw e.Exception));
```

And now it works properly.

I guess the reason is that **Invoke** method left the EventHandler blocked and now the **BeginInvoke** method doesn't.